# Meta robots noindex follow

Tags: seo

If a popular website has

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow"/>
```

on it's page

and that website in turn has a backlink to my website (dofollow backlink). Will it increase my SERP or not?

Comment: The noindex directive indicates to search engines like Google not to index the content of the page, despite following the links on it. While the backlink itself is "followed" (meaning search engine crawlers will follow it to your site), the lack of indexing on the referring page means that search engines won't associate your site with any ranking signals from that particular page. Therefore, the impact on your SERP ranking from such a backlink would likely be minimal or non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

However we take JohnMu's advice with a grain of salt, according to our tests the "noindex, follow" in time becomes "noindex, nofollow".

Unless it's a really low-hanging fruit, I wouldn't dwell on it.